# How to access default input value from controller

Tags: angularjs

Input field contains JSON data set from some other script.I have to access in controller.How can I access it in controller.Code I am using something like this-

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Controller</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
        <div ng-app="" ng-controller="studentController">
            Enter first name: <input class="get" type="text" ng-model="student">
        </div>
        <script>
            function studentController($scope) {
                console.log($scope.student);
            }
        </script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to study the tutorial of AngularJS..

Comment: Like @Ved said, learn angular, it's **very** **very** basic thing, what you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular, the controller is who tells the View what the default value should be  (not the other way around). The View would reflect that, and could update it (with `ng-model`), but it is initially set by the controller.

So, the controller knows because the controller sets it up:

```
.controller("studentController", function($scope){
    $scope.student = "default name";
});
```